# html tags changing but no change made on form

Tags: javascript, html, tapestry

I am using the following code to change the attributes of a tag on my form

the tag

```
<input jwcid="licensingApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker" disabled="ognl:disabled || isLicensingApprovalDateDisabled()"
            value="ognl:company.licensingApprovalDate" displayName="message:company.licensingApprovalDate"/>
```

the code to add new attributes to the above tag

```
function checkForChange(field) {
    var approvalStatus = document.getElementById('licensingStatus').value;
    if(approvalStatus == "Pass"){
        document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday,required");
    } else {
        document.getElementById('licensingApprovalDate').setAttribute("validators", "validators:maxDateToday");
    }   
}
```

this function is being called when ever licensingStatus is changed, it is working and when i inspect the element when the licensingStatus is changed the tag is changed correctly but this should add an * next to the licensingApprovalDate input box but it doesn't

Is there a way for the changes to take place the second the tag/licensinggStatus is changed?

Comment: I don't see any "tag" changing here. Do you mean when the VALUE changes?

Comment: What do you mean when it has changed? And by tag, you mean textbox?

Comment: Edit to question: I tagged this "tapestry" as a Google search of `jwcid` resulted in tapestry results.  As I am unfamiliar with tapestry, so please excuse if I've tagged incorrectly.

Comment: when the function is called, it adds a new attribute to the `<input>` tag, what i want to do is refresh `licensingApprovalDate@CustomDatePicker` when the new attribute is added to the `<input>` tag

Comment: "but this should also change my page a small bit but nothing is happening"... what do you mean? What changes are you expecting?

Comment: if licensingStatus is set to Pass then the attribute `validators:maxDateToday,required` is added to the `<input>` tag, this will add a * next to the input box for licensingApprovalDate, this * means that it is a required field, but when this attribute is added to the tag the * does not appear until you refresh the page

Comment: because that stuff is done on the server and not the clientside.

Answer (score 0):

validators is a parameter, and not an attribute. It appears in the template as an attribute because, hey, it's kinda XML.

Tapestry 3 was not designed for this level of dynamic behavior (it was cutting edge in 2003 though!).  Given that its 2012, please consider an upgrade to Tapestry 5!